# Why does conversion from seconds (with millisecond precision) as float to Time in ruby result in an inconsistent precision loss in ruby?

Tags: ruby

When using the `Time.at` function to convert a float representing seconds since epoch (with millisecond precision) and then extracting the microsecond value the result is inconsistent precision loss.

For example, using the 1st of January for every year since 1970:

```sh
ruby -e 'require("time");p (1..50).map {|offset| Time.at(Time.parse("#{1970+offset}-01-01T00:00:0.123}").to_r.numerator/1000.0).usec}'
[122999, 123000, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 123000, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999, 122999]
```

Based on the discussion in https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7829 - I would have expected the sub-second value to always have a loss of precision (i.e. always be `122999`).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR (from [`Time#to_f`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#method-i-to_f))

> Note that IEEE 754 double is not accurate enough to represent the exact number of nanoseconds since the Epoch.

---

Regarding your expectation:

> I would have expected the sub-second value to always have a loss of precision (i.e. always be 122999).

loss ≠ less. A *"loss in precision"* doesn't mean that the result is always *less* than the actual value. For example, adding `0.1` and `0.2` results in a value that slightly *above* `0.3`, due to precision loss:

```
0.1 + 0.2 #=> 0.30000000000000004
```

Back to your time values. Let's just take the first two  years, 1971 and 1972:

```
Time.parse('1971-01-01T00:00:0.123').to_f #=> 31532400.123
Time.parse('1972-01-01T00:00:0.123').to_f #=> 63068400.123

Time.at(31532400.123).usec #=> 122999
Time.at(63068400.123).usec #=> 123000
```

This happens because of floating point inaccuracy. The float's *actual* values are:

```
31532400.1229999996721744537353515625
63068400.123000003397464752197265625
#        ^^^^^^
#         usec
```

Calling `nsec` reveals that both of the above are in fact inaccurate: (one slightly below, the other slightly above)

```
Time.at(31532400.123).nsec #=> 122999999
Time.at(63068400.123).nsec #=> 123000003
```

To get precise values, you have to provide precise arguments:

```
Time.at(31532400123.quo(1000)).usec #=> 12300

# or

Time.at(31532400, 123000).usec #=> 12300
```